# SARIMAX Not Callable

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm trying to fit a SARIMAX model, but keep getting an error that it is not callable. My code is:

```
import statsmodels as sm
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.sarimax(vol_p_1d,trend='n',order=(1,0,1),seasonal_order=(1,1,1,12))
```

The error message is:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The model is in capital letters (python class naming convention) SARIMAX, all lower case sarimax is the name of the module.

Comment: also, full path is statsmodel.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX, but using the api `import statsmodels.api as sm` the shorter path is available `sm.tsa.SARIMAX`

Comment: Thanks! I found it now

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @Josef

> The model is in capital letters (python class naming convention)
>   SARIMAX, all lower case sarimax is the name of the module. – Josef Jul
>   17 '17 at 19:54
>
> also, full path is statsmodel.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX, but
>   using the api import statsmodels.api as sm the shorter path is
>   available sm.tsa.SARIMAX – Josef Jul 17 '17 at 19:59

As was mentioned in the comments, the issue here comes from the naming convention. I just had a similar issue, due to the same misuse.

My issue:

- Jupyter: No results from "sarima" after several minutes. Even for small parameters
- CMD: Same thing. No result output saved to files I'd designated

I was about to search for how to speed up or optimize it, or at least figure out why my sarima results were talking so long.

The fix is to make sure you use something like:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace import sarimax

... etc

some_model = sarimax.SARIMAX(daytuh, order = (p,d,q), seasonal_order = (P,D,Q), ...)
```

where the p d q P D Q are integers inside a tuple.